# Make a diamond bright

Tags: jewelry

I have a platinum ring and I want to put a diamond on it. Is there a possibility to make the diamond "looking bright in the day" ? By this I mean that the diamond would look like if he was emitting light even in the day.

I have a thing to propose :

Putting a fluorescent/phosphorescent stuff between the diamond and the ring. What do you think?

Comment: Is this an actual, serious question? It doesn't sound like one at all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "fluorescent/phosphorescent stuff" will not emit enough light to be visible during daytime. You could put a LED light underneath, but even with a small battery it will become quite bulky and unseemly. But being an open-ended question, asking to generate ideas, this is not a good fit for this website (a "right" answer being subjective)—unless you're only really asking if putting the "fluorescent/phosphorescent stuff" would work; if so, please [edit] your question to reflect that, or it will probably get closed.

Comment: Hi, thanks Joachim. In fact, it's an open-ended question. So yes, it's more about finding alternatives to "fluorescent/phosphorescent stuff" since (as you've pointed out) it  will not emit enough light.

Comment: What are the shortest led you have in mind?

Comment: Surface mount LEDs can be sub millimetre, so the battery would be the main concern

Comment: @AllisonC - yeah, that is the trouble with diamonds, they are just not bright enough!

Comment: @rebusB The OP could have been talking about rough diamonds, though, and a perfectly reasonable answer would have been "cut and polish it" :)

Comment: Hi, ok. So a little LED would be ok and the problem would be with the battery.

Comment: Yes Allison C. It's a serious question though a little bit extravagant. I'm sorry if you think I lack you of respect.